# How to compile/package Spark 2.0 project with external jars and Maven

Tags: xml, scala, maven, apache-spark, centos

Since version 2.0, Apache Spark is bundled with a folder "jars" full of .jar files. Obviously Maven will download all these jars when issuing:

```
mvn -e package
```

because in order to submit an application with

```
spark-submit --class DataFetch target/DataFetch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

the **DataFetch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar** is needed.

So, the first question is straightforward, how can I take advantage of these existing jars?. The second question is related, son I've tried the first time with Maven downloading the jars, I've got the following output:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building "DataFetch" 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @DataFetch ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory     /root/sparkTests/scalaScripts/DataFetch/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ DataFetch -    --
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ DataFetch ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory/root/sparkTests/scalaScripts/DataFetch/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ DataFetch ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ DataFetch ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /root/sparkTests/scalaScripts/DataFetch/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ DataFetch---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.294s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 28 17:41:29 PYT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/71M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.spark.pg</groupId>
  <artifactId>DataFetch</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>"DataFetch"</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  

</project>
```

If more information is needed, please don't hesitate to ask for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand your problem, but I try to answer.

Based on **Spark Bundling Your Application’s Dependencies** documentation:

> When creating assembly jars, list Spark and Hadoop as provided
>   dependencies; these need not be bundled since they are provided by the
>   cluster manager at runtime.

You can set scope to **provided** in maven pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
    <!-- add this scope -->
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The second think I noticed is that maven build creates empty JAR.

```
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
```

If you have any other dependencies, you should package these dependencies into final jar archive file.

You can do something like below in pom.xml and run ***mvn package***:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- package with project dependencies -->
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>YOUR_MAIN_CLASS</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Maven log should print line with building jar:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.4.1:single (make-assembly) @ dateUtils ---
[INFO] Building jar: path/target/APPLICATION_NAME-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

After maven packaging phase in the target folder you should see **DataFetch-1.0-SNAPSHOTjar-with-dependencies.jar** and you can sumbit this jar with *spark-submit*

Comment: Yes, you got it right, i'll do some tests and let you know if this works.

Comment: did it works as you want? or did you find out where was a problem with packaging?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just tested it, and no, I've got the exact same output.
    `[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ DataFetch ---`
    `[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!`
    `[INFO] Building jar: /root/sparkTests/scalaScripts/DataFetch/target/DataFetch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: I do have the correct archetype too: ../DataFetch/src/main/scala/com/spark/pg. My sources are in the `/com/spark/pg` package. This whas created with mvn archetype:generate

Comment: @Emiliano - Based on [this](http://whileonefork.blogspot.sk/2011/06/beginning-scala-building-project-with.html) for scala you have to use maven-scala-plugin. Check [claudera packagin scala example](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_develop_run.html#wordcount__section_iz2_vbb_h5).

And if you have your DataFetch class in a package you have to pass full path to --class parameter in `spark-submit`. eg: `spark-submit --class  com.spark.pg.DataFetch --master local DataFetch-1.0-SNAPSHOTjar-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: Thanks a lot @VladoDemcak, the guide was helpful. Now I can compile/package and run my project in my server without any issue. I was actually missing the maven-scala-plugin, and with that and scala_2.11.8 version, went all ok.