# The error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when running spark-submit

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I want run spark-submit for my Scala Spark application. These are the steps I did:

1) execute Maven Clean and Package from IntellijIDEA to get myTest.jar
2) execute the following spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --name 28 --master local[2] --class org.test.consumer.TestRunner \
/usr/tests/test1/target/myTest.jar \
$arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5
```

This is the `TestRunner` object that I want to run:

```
package org.test.consumer

import org.test.consumer.kafka.KafkaConsumer

object TestRunner {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val Array(zkQuorum, group, topic1, topic2, kafkaNumThreads) = args

    val processor = new KafkaConsumer(zkQuorum, group, topic1, topic2)
    processor.run(kafkaNumThreads.toInt)

  }

}
```

But the `spark-submit` command fails with the following message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.test.consumer.TestRunner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
```

I don't really understand why the object `TestRunner` cannot be found, if the package is specified correctly... Has it something to do with the usage of `object` instead of `class`?

**UPDATE:**

The project structure (the folder `scala` is currently marked as **Sources**):

```
/usr/tests/test1
  .idea
  src
    main
      docker
      resources
      scala
        org
          test
             consumer
                kafka
                    KafkaConsumer.scala
                TestRunner.scala
    test
  target
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>consumer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sedis</groupId>
            <artifactId>sedis_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lambdaworks</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacks_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib-local_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.nscala-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>nscala-time_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: I am almost sure you have not packaged your jar correctly. Take a look into jar file (in total commander or winrar ...) and check whether the class TestRunner is in this jar. If there isnt chceck whether you are using scala plugin in maven correctly.

Comment: check your jar with `jar tf /usr/tests/test1/target/myTest.jar` add `| grep TestRunner` if you're on a Linux system.

Comment: It would be great if you can you provide your directory structure.

Comment: @ViacheslavRodionov: Yes, I am on Linux. I runned this command. Should there be any output in case of error? I didn't get any output.

Comment: @VladoDemcak: Thanks. Yes, most probably it's the case. I am trying to assign different folders inside the project as "Sources" and then do `mvn -Dscala-2.11 clean package`. The same issue all the time. How can I discover whether the class TestRunner is in the jar?

Comment: @VladoDemcak: Ok, I just unzipped the jar file and inside the maven folder I only see `org.test`, then inside this folder there is another one `consumer` and inside it I see only `pom.properties` and `pom.xml`. There is no `TestRunner.scala` or any other scala files.

Comment: Well, your source directory is totally wrong or absent, it has nothing to do with Spark. Please read some introduction to maven. Try at least not using `-Dscala-2.11`? As @RITZXAVI said we will need your dir structure and also pom.xml.

Comment: @ViacheslavRodionov: I made updates to my Thread and published both the project's structure and pom.xml.

Comment: Jar is basically just archive wit .jar sufix and you can unzip or open it in winrar for example. check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758169/how-to-compile-package-spark-2-0-project-with-external-jars-and-maven/39776529) there was maybe similar problem and it should help you - sorry for delay meanwhile you added new comment

Comment: @VladoDemcak: Thanks. I published updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@FiofanS, the problem is in your directory structure.

Maven uses a `convention over configuratation` policy. It means, by default, maven expects that you will follow the set of rules that it has defined. For example, it expects you to put all your code in `src/main/java` directory (See [Maven Standard Directory Structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)). But you don't have your code in `src/main/java` directory. Instead, you have it in `src/main/scala` directory. By default, maven will not consider `src/main/scala` as source location.

Although , maven expects you to follow the rules it has defined, but it doesn't enforce them. It also provides you ways in which you can configure things based on your preference.
In your case, you will have to explicitly instruct maven to consider `src/main/scala` also as one of your source location.

To do this, you will have to use the [Maven Build Helper Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/index.html).
Add the below piece of code within the `<project>...</project>` tag in your pom.xml

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/main/scala</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried this solution. In particular, I defined source as `<sources>
                                <source>src/main/scala</source>
                            </sources>`. Is this correct? Then I executed Clean and Package from Intellij to get the new jar file. After this I runned `spark-submit` and received the same problem. I also unzipped the jar file to see the content. I didn't see any scala class inside its folders. Only pom.xml and pom.properties. BTW, should I manifest main class?

Comment: Yes, probably you will have to add the main class in the manifest file. But that is not the problem here, The problem is why your TestRunner class not being packaged even after using the build helper plugin. Are you sure, you have added the exact code I mentioned above ? Also, do one thing, for now just use the command `mvn clean install` and tell us if the TestRunner class was packaged in the jar or not.

Comment: or just use `sbt` ;)

Comment: you will need maven-scala-plugin i suppose

Comment: I finally copied-pasted the build part from this simple scala-maven project: https://github.com/jesperdj/scala-maven-example/blob/master/pom.xml, and it works now! it's similar to your solution with some additional modifications.

Comment: The only issue is that now I have exceptions like: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory`. I appreciate if you can help. Anyway I accepted the answer as the main problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you. Can you open another question for this. We might have to provide you with some code. It wouldn't be right to post that code as an answer here for this post.

Comment: Once you are done posting a new question, please provide the link to that question here.

Comment: @RITZXAVI: Thanks. I published the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046021/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-typesafe-config-configfactory-when-packaging