# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory when packaging Scala project with Maven

Tags: scala, maven

This question is a continuation of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041657/the-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-when-running-spark-submit).

The problem that I have refers to packaging Scala Spark project using Maven.

When I run this command:

```
spark-submit --name 28 --master local[2] --class org.test.consumer.TestRunner \
/usr/tests/test1/target/test_service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
$arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5
```

..., I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory
    at org.test.consumer.kafka.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.scala:38)
    at org.test.consumer.TestRunner$.main(TestRunner.scala:19)
    at org.test.consumer.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
```

This is my current `pom.xml` that considers the recommendations from the thread mentioned above (I checked that generated jar contains scala classes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test.consumer</groupId>
    <artifactId>test_service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sedis</groupId>
            <artifactId>sedis_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lambdaworks</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacks_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib-local_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.nscala-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>nscala-time_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Configure maven-compiler-plugin to use the desired Java version -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Use build-helper-maven-plugin to add Scala source and test source directories -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/scala</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/test/scala</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Use scala-maven-plugin for Scala support -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <!-- Need to specify this explicitly, otherwise plugin won't be called when doing e.g. mvn compile -->
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Looks like `com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory` belongs to a library. Have you included that library in your pom.xml ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that you don't have to add this jar if it is already present.

Looks like the jar should be an executable jar with all your dependencies packaged within the jar file.
You will have to use the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) to do that.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>org.sample.App</mainClass>    // put your main class here.
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

This plugin will create an additional jar (apart from the regular jar) with the name appended with `-jar-with-dependencies`. Use this jar instead of using the original jar.

Comment: Hmm, still the same issue after cleaning and packaging jar file. BTW I didn't add any jar manually to the project's path, and previously it compiled without even adding this dependency. So, maybe it overrides with some other dependency? Also, the same issue appeared for `kafka.utils.Logging`, but I just commented it out.

Comment: Probably you will have to package the dependencies also within the jar. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I cannot believe that it finally worked!!! Thank you so much! I am using `test_service-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`, because actually packaging generated 2 jars.

Comment: I am glad that my answer helped you :-) . And yes, you will have to use the fat jar that this plugin created. Btw Mind upvoting my answer?

Comment: I accepted your answer, but cannot upvote it until I get the reputation greater than 15. I will upvote it once I have sufficient reputation (btw, upvoting the question can speedup this process;)